# getting a variable value in a Behavior Class

Tags: php, yii

How do i get the variable `$mapCommentColumn`'s value in my model class?

This is my `CommentableBehavior` class in my `modules/comment/behaviors/CommentableBehavior.php`

```
class CommentableBehavior extends CActiveRecordBehavior
{
    /**
     * @var string name of the table defining the relation with comment and model
     */
    public $mapTable = null;
    /**
     * @var string name of the table column holding commentId in mapTable
     */
    public $mapCommentColumn = 'commentId';
    /**
     * @var string name of the table column holding related Objects Id in mapTable
     */
    public $mapRelatedColumn = null;

    .......

}
```

in my `modules/comment/models/comment.php`

```
protected function beforeSave()
    {   
        $commentedModel = CActiveRecord::model($this->module->commentableModels[$this->type]);
        $db = array(
            'join' => "JOIN " . $this->mapTable . " cm ON t.id = cm." . $this->mapCommentColumn,
            'condition' => "cm." . $this->mapYearColumn . "=:year
                            AND t.pending=:pending",
            'params' => array(':year'=>$_GET['year'], ':pending'=>0)
        );
        print_r(CommentableBehavior::getCommentCount($db));

 }
```

i want to get `$this->mapTable` and `$this->mapCommentColumn` from my `CommentableBehavior` class. any ideas? Thanks

i get this error at the `print_r()`

```
<h1>CException</h1> <p>Property "CommentModule.mapTable" is not defined. (/Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php:1‌​30)</p><pre>#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(105): CComponent->__get('mapTable')
```

Comment: have you get any error ?

Comment: Have you added behaviours in your model class?

Comment: @YatinMistry how do i add it in my model class? i get this error at the `print_r()`  .... `<h1>CException</h1>
<p>Property "CommentModule.mapTable" is not defined. (/Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php:130)</p><pre>#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(105): CComponent->__get('mapTable')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `modules/comment/models/comment.php` put

```
public function behaviors() 
{
    return array(
        'commentable'=>array(
            'class'=>'comment.behaviors.CommentableBehavior', 
        ),
    );
}
```

you call it by `$this->mapTable` or `$this->commentable->mapTable`